# Reg: sysdba not logging, system user and other user connecting

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, database-administration, sysdba

Sysdba not logging other users are logging below,   how to

fix it, able to login to other users successfully, please find below, only with sysdba not working

```
 [oracle@dztupbin]$ ./sqlplus SYSTEM/"oracle"
  
    SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Thu Apr 28 11:05:09 2022
    Copyright (c) 1982, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
    Last Successful login time: Thu Apr 28 2022 11:05:00 +01:00
    Connected to:
    Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
    
    [oracle@dztup bin]$ ./sqlplus SYSTEM/"oracle"  as sysdba
    
    SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Thu Apr 28 11:05:18 2022
    
    Copyright (c) 1982, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
    
    ERROR:
    ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
    
    
    Enter user-name:
```

sqlplus / as sysdba also giving same result:-

./sqlplus / as sysdba

```
ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied




[oracle@dztup bin]$ ./sqlplus /  as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Thu Apr 28 11:05:18 2022

Copyright (c) 1982, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied


Enter user-name:
```

I connected to sys user now:-

```
[oracle@dztup bin]$ ./sqlplus system/"oracle"

SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Thu Apr 28 13:25:51 2022

Copyright (c) 1982, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Last Successful login time: Thu Apr 28 2022 13:25:15 +01:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> conn sys as sysdba
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL>
SQL>
SQL>
SQL> show user
USER is "SYS"
```

granted sysdba privilige to system user now able to connect:

but still sqlplus / as sysdba not working.
[oracle@dztup bin]$ ./sqlplus /  as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Thu Apr 28 11:05:18 2022

Copyright (c) 1982, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

Answer (score 0):

`SYSDBA` is a privilege, not a user. The `SYSTEM` account does not have `SYSDBA` privileges, by default. The only account with default `SYSDBA` privileges is `SYS`, which is usually authenticated locally by the operating system. e.g.:

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
```

If you have granted `SYSDBA` privileges to other users, then those users are authenticated against a separate password file when logging in with the `SYSDBA` role, and not the normal password hash. The password file is not updated automatically when the users' normal password is changed (as with `ALTER USER x IDENTIFIED BY pass`). To update the password in the password file you must re-grant `SYSDBA` privileges to the user; otherwise use the old password.

Comment: for sqlplus / as sysdba also getting this error: ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

Comment: Any comments  can you suggest

Comment: If you're using OS authentication (sqlplus / as sysdba) then you'll need to be logged in to the server as the user that owns the Oracle software and running processes.

Comment: yes oracle cat /etc/group
oracle is member in dba group previously it was working fine, so we have all the password files and data.